# How do you know if you need multiple indexes or one bigger index?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been tasked with optimizing a db that is mostly read, and I was given the lead of using DMV queries by Glenn Berry. Well, I'm looking at 3 "missing indexes" that might be helpful, but they look so similar. They're the same table, and it looks like one large index would cover everything needed across the 3 possible indexes.

How do I know if I should create one for all of them, or if I should create individual indexes (in which case I would only create 1 or 2 of them)?

Second, Is there a way to tell how many commonly executed queries would use a potential index?

I haven't as of yet gotten to learning how to actually create them, I have been focusing on *if* I should make them. What I am going off of is information from Berry's DMV script for Missing Indexes.

```
index_advantage
Index 1- 24291.95
Index 2- 830.71
Index 3- 21.51

equality_columns
Index 1- [MessageType],[ConnectionID],[EndDateTime],[ManualEndDateTime],[SupportClose]
Index 2- [MessageType],[EndDateTime],[ManualEndDateTime],[SupportClose]
Index3- [ConnectionID]

included_columns
Index 1- NULL
Index 2- NULL
Index 3- [ID], [Username], [MachineName], [Message], [MessageType], [ConnectionName], [ConnectionTypeName], [EndDateTime], [LoggedUserName], [GroupName], [StartDateTimeUTC], [EndDateTimeUTC], [Cost], [Comment], [Prompt], [Data], [ManualEndDateTime], [UserInfoID], [ManualClosedBy], [SecurityGroup], [SupportClose], [OpenMode], [CloseMode], [HostName], [IsEmbedded], [ClosePrompt], [Status], [ActivityDuration], [DataSourceID], [CreationDate], [ActiveTime], [Application], [Version], [IsPrivate], [PrivateUserID], [CustomerID], [ConnectionUsername]
```

Table is the same for all 3, inequality_columns is the same for all 3.

Comment: It sounds like you need to dig deeper into understanding how indexes work. This series is an amazing line of articles on this topic. It starts super basic and goes pretty deep as it progresses. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72399/

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out.

Comment: The answer to the question in your title:  You learn how indexes are used.  You figure out the optimal indexes for your query(s).  You then trade-off simplicity with optimality.

Comment: Can you add the create script for the 3 missing indexes? I don't know your data but I would always try to create as few indexes as possible to satisfy the broadest range of queries.

Comment: Edited with some more information. I'll start reading the stuff Sean linked in the meantime.

Comment: Indexing is not straightforward, this is science and art in one. Your optimizer may suggest a perfectly good looking index, which would ruin overall performance of your app if implemented. You look at the queries, check what fields are used for joins and where clauses, and what fields are output, and decide which indices to implement after testing different combinations. If you have 2 queries that use a similar set of output columns and the same where/join clauses, you may get away with 1 index. But if your queries are completely different, you may need multiple different indices.

Comment: Ok, I get the gist. Thanks everyone for your comments!

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though the answer to this is going to be far more complex than I was hoping it would be. I think I'm going to have to learn a lot more myself and apply what I learn in order to do this successfully.

Thanks everyone for your comments!